# Picture goes to a new page when inserted

Tags: floats

I have now managed to insert a picture into my LaTeX...but now, I cannot place it where I want it to go :/

For some bizarre reason, the picture, when inserted, goes to the next page, a new page, automatically. Here is my work,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Math Notes for Melba}
\author{soconfusedwithlatex}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{blahblah}
shall insert now
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{sets1.png}
 \caption{Set A on the left and set B on the right}
\end{figure}
```

So, I have tried altering the size of the picture to make sure it fits..but I am sure LaTeX is doing something weird to send it to a new page. I made it really small it obviously fits into the remaining space in the previous page.

Someone said \usepackage{float} helps but putting it in didn't solve the issue....how do I make it stop sending it to new pages? Thanks!

Comment: The behaviour is in no point bizarre. That is what floats are for. Use `\begin{figure}[H]` instead.

Comment: I would just not use `figure` if you don't want it to move. Perhaps `\begin{center}...\end{center}` would be better. To get the caption, use the `\captionof` command from either `caption` or `capt-of`. By the way, `10.5pt` is not an option recognised by `article`. Removing it will have precisely the same effect without the warnings caused by using it.

Comment: Please don't promote `[H]`, that is not what floats are for. Better explain the proper usage of the optional parameters for floats. Usually you'd want to use `[htp]` or `[htbp]` to insure that it is placed as close to this location as possible. `[h]` means here if possible, and would require that there is text material above and below or else it is turned into a `[t]`

Comment: If you want people to see your problem, replace `\includegraphics` by `\rule{2cm}{1cm}` which will make a black rectangle, make it whatever size shows the problem.

Comment: Note that the _only_ purpose of the `figure` environment is to allow latex to move the figure. (otherwise you could just use `\includegraphics`)  but it is impossible to say why it is moving it in this particular case unless you complete the example so it can be reproduced.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agreeing in principle. maybe i have seen to many users arguing that they know best where a graphic should be, not listening to any reasons.

Answer (score 3):

There is several solutions you can you force the float environnement to NOT be a float environnement by writing `[H]` instead of `[h]` but it's not a good way.

The best solution is to not used any float environnement:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{Math Notes for Melba}
\author{soconfusedwithlatex}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{blahblah}
shall insert now
\begin{center}
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{sans.png}
 \captionof{figure}{Set A on the left and set B on the right}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```